# Integrate Codeigniter and Filterable

Tags: codeigniter, filter

I'm trying to integrate *Codeigniter* and *Filterable* but I cant find much information about it. I have a page with many results and I want to filter the results, for example by the column "name" or "id". I have worked with Filterable before, but never had to do it with Codeigniter.

I tried to put the files on the root. Also in the folder "Application", even tried putting it on the same folder as the view. But in any of these cases I cannot link the files and get it to work.

The ways I've been trying to link the scripts are the following:

1. `<script src="<?php echo site_url('src/filterable.js')?>"></script>` This was with the scripts in application folder
2. `<script src="./src/filterable.js"></script>` Scripts on root
3. `<script src="<?php echo site_url('admin/src/filterable.js')?>"></script>`  Scripts on view folder

Is there another way to achieve this? Or maybe another library I could use for it?

Comment: Please never put "solved" or similar into the title.  Simply "accepting" the appropriate answer below is how this site indicates a question has been "solved".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks AdrienXL for your answer. I tried to follow your suggestion but in the end I couldn't make it work. For some reason Codeigniter didn't recognize the files I tried to reach.

So after a long searching I ran across a library called *Datatables* http://www.datatables.net/ it has the option to load the scripts locally or remotely, so just added the link to the scripts needed to the type of filter I had to implement and in the end this last option was what allowed me to make the filters work.

Comment: Please be considerate of helping future readers by making your answer more "self-contained".  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky I'm sorry but this is my first time posting a question into a forum. I don't usually like to ask these questions, but was an ultimate resource. Also English is not my native language. Can you explain what do you mean with "Self-contained", please?

Comment: It means, don't make the reader have to guess what "Datatables" means.  Give us a direct link to the "Datatables" library and clearly explain why/how this solved the original problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I like to deal with assets.

I create an helper called assets_helper in application/helpers/

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('js'))
{
    function js($nom)
    {
        return '<script src="' . base_url() . 'assets/js/' . $nom . '.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>';
    }
}
//This is only the part that handle js as it is what's bothering you
```

Here is the full helper I use : http://pastebin.com/ujETEXJ4

After that, at the same level as index.php I create those folder :

```
|-Application
|-System
|-index.php
|-Assets
    |- css
    |- sass
    |- images
    |- js
```

Put all the js file you need in your new js folder.

In my application/config/autoload.php I add my new helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('assets', ...);
```

Finally, in the footer of my page(s) :

```
<?= js('myjsfile'); ?> //I did not forgot the extension, it's how it works :)
```

Which will give at the end :

```
 <script src="http://www.example.com/assets/js/myjsfile.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: The problem here is that your proposed file structure only works when you've put everything into the www/public HTML/"web root" directory.  Typically, for best CodeIgniter security, the CodeIgniter `Application` and `System` directories should be installed up one level higher than that.  See "For the best security":  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html